Timezone mismatch in Docker container using ubuntu:24.04 but not with ubuntu:22.04
I am experiencing a timezone error inside a Docker container using the ubuntu:24.04 base image. This issue does not occur when I use the ubuntu:22.04 base image. Here is a minimal reproducible example.
22.04:
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/etc/localtime,target=/etc/localtime,readonly --mount type=bind,source=/etc/timezone,target=/etc/timezon,readonly ubuntu:22.04 bash

24.04:
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/etc/localtime,target=/etc/localtime,readonly --mount type=bind,source=/etc/timezone,target=/etc/timezon,readonly ubuntu:24.04 bash

Host system timezone: /etc/localtime is a symlink to /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago.
Docker container with ubuntu:24.04: /etc/localtime is a symlink to /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC.
I have tried mounting the host's timezone files into the container:
# timezone synchronization with host
- /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

Despite this, the timezone inside the container does not match the host's timezone. The tzlocal.get_localzone() function works on the host but throws an error inside the container:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/tzlocal/unix.py", line 180, in _get_localzone
    tzname = _get_localzone_name(_root)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/tzlocal/unix.py", line 159, in _get_localzone_name
    raise zoneinfo.ZoneInfoNotFoundError(message)
zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'Multiple conflicting time zone configurations found:
    /etc/timezone: America/Chicago
    /etc/localtime is a symlink to: Etc/UTC
    Fix the configuration, or set the time zone in a TZ environment variable.'
The problem seems specific to ubuntu:24.04. How can I ensure the container correctly reflects the host's timezone settings?

Additional Information:
I prefer not to explicitly set the timezone inside the Dockerfile.
Installing tzdata and other dependencies does not seem to resolve the issue.
Any advice on how to resolve this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated!
I suspect that Ubuntu 24.04 automatically overwrittes the symlink to UTC time (/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC)

There is a typo in the example calls: timezon instead of timezone.

Ah! Just a typo! It is very likely that was causing the problem. Since the Docker's timezone was not getting updated correctly, it was using the default timezone (UTC). That would make sense.

/etc/localtime must be a symlink, but it is a normal file in your example:
$ docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/etc/localtime,target=/etc/localtime,readonly ubuntu:24.04 bash
root@48ee615ac631:/# ls -l /etc/localtime 
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 2298 Dec  3 14:19 /etc/localtime

That is probably the reason why Python assumes that /etc/localtime is pointing to the default Etc/UTC.
